# Run time a class implement an interface in Java?

Tags: java

Lets say I have class like:

```
class A
{
}
```

by any means I can make the class `implements` an interface on the **runtime**?

This is what I'm trying to achieve, when some one creates object of class `A`, I need to intercept the calls to that object.

Very new to Java, thanks.

Comment: write `class A implements InterfaceB`

Comment: No. Why would you want that? Either the class does implement the interface definition or it doesn't.

Please state what exactly you want to achieve with that.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Obviously he wants the implementation on runtime, not on compilation...

Comment: What would you want to achieve by implementing an interface at runtime? It's a type declaration and usually has a severe impact on how you need to to write your class.

Comment: But why downvotes? I need it on runtime, as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: I'm also not a big fan of the downvoting, but it's probably due to the fact that you're asking for something really strange to every Java developer without explaining why you even would need such a thing. Explain in more detail and we can probably find a better solution for you.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve, when some one creates object of class A, I need to intercept the calls to that object.

Comment: why do you need implement interface during runtime? What do you want to achieve? I'm not saying it cant be done (i think asm allows you to manipulate bytecode on runtime) but is it worth to do this, or you just have bad and nasty design

Comment: @user902383 This is quite customary in Spring-based applications, where dynamic proxies are created which implement additional, framework-specific interfaces. This is a fully legitimate request and many programmers use it, just without being aware of it.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson  i did't went too deep into spring proxies, but can you really use them to add interface to class?

Comment: @user902383 As I explain in my answer, the interface is added to a dynamic *subclass* of your class.

Answer (score 2):

A class cannot be made to implement an interface at runtime. The best that can be done at runtime is creating a dynamic *subclass* of your class, which additionally implements an interface.

By the Liskov Substitution Principle this solution will work quite well because any code written against your type `A` will also work against its subtypes. Also, any code written against the interface you are implementing will also work and be able to access the behavior implemented in your class `A`, to the extent to which this behavior is reflected through the behavior of the interface's methods.

Comment: @JamesB A code example would be specific to a dynamic class creation library; that would be a little heavyweight and it wouldn't be much helpful since in practice, these maneuvers are executed by a framework, not client code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), however I wouldn't do this unless you know Java AND Byte Code very well and there really isn't another option.

A better option is to use composition or inheritance

```
class A {
}

class B extend A implement I {
     // B is an A and implements I
}
A a = new B();

class C implement I {
     A a;
}
```

Either B or C implement your interface without having to change A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Proxy` object to adapt any object at run time to make it appear as if it implements an interface.

There is a nice article [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue108.html) that discusses a factory method for doing this to objects.

Essentially, a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) object can be used to wrap an object by intercepting all method calls to the object and redirecting them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solvable with an adapter. Have an other class defined that implements your interface and delegates to the real object:

```
class YourAdapter implements YourInterface {

    private final YourClass realObject;

    public YourAdapter(YourClass realObject) {
        this.realObject = realObject;
    }

    @Override
    public methodFromInterface() {            
        realObject.methodFromInterface();
    }

    // .......

}
```

Now, given a method that expects `YourInterface` and an object of type YourClass:

```
void someMethod(YourInterface param) {}

void test() {
    YourClass object = getFromSomewhere();
    someMethod( YourAdapter(object) );
}
```

**2nd way :**
Using Proxy class :

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) link.

[Example](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2007/11/22/mimicry-in-action-dynamically-implement-an-interface-using-dynamic-proxy/) of dynamically implement an interface using Dynamic Proxy